# Loading a layout after Activity is shown

Tags: java, android, layout, android-activity

I have a pretty resource-intensive layout that I need to be loaded, and it works on my Nexus 4, with about a second of delay. I can't imagine what it'd be like on slower devices, which is it's primary use; hence I need a way to load the activity, and show a blank layout. Then build the layout as the device buffers it. I've tried putting `setContentView(R.layout.main);` in an `AsyncTask`, but the problem still persists (probably because I'm calling it during the `onCreate`). Does anyone have any advice on how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: A little bit like the Facebook app, but not quite. Something that loads the backgound, then loads the information as it's processed, not waiting till it's all pre-loaded and then shown.

Answer (score 0):

Show a blank layout, perhaps with a progress bar, an activity indicator, or even a default image. When you have the layout prepared, swap it in. If you want to display parts of the UI as they become available, load individual views.

A layout is the overall framework for your UI. You should show it ASAP when your app starts, so that users know that your app is there. After that, you can put in resources as you go.

Glance at the sample app for [Sending Operations to Multiple Threads](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html). This is an image viewer that has a rather uninteresting main layout. The images display as they are decoded.

Comment: One of the biggest problems i'm having is to do with the activity not starting properly. Problem is, I have code for a thread to be ran off the onCreate method, and that thread loads the menu and then replaces it, this solves the application crashing, but the problem is the activity doesn't show up until the thread itself has finished.. Which is just annoying.. I need it so that the activity shows, it's blank as you said with an activity indicator or whatever, and then when the layout is buffered, it replaces it, on the activity. This is my problem :/ Regardless thanks for the help though :)